# How to display FormArray data in FormGroup if such data is dependent on several Observable?

Tags: angular, observable, formarray

I have wasted several days trying to display asychronously dynamically loaded FormArray data and no luck.
In short, I have `FormGroup` which is created on click and displayed in a modal window (no problem with displaying data loaded in subscribe of Ordinance entity details API call (data is loaded into `selectedOrdinance` object):

```js
      buildOrdinanceForm() {
        this.ordinanceForm = this.fb.group({
          ordinanceId: this.selectedOrdinance.ordinanceId // already available, loaded via API call to Ordinance details page in service observable 'subscribe'
          ...
          ordinanceLanguages: new FormArray([]) // trouble here - data needs to be loaded asynchronously using another API
        });
        ...
      }
    
     get ordinanceLanguages$(): Observable<FormArray> {
        return combineLatest([
          this.languageCodesLookupData$,
          of(this.selectedOrdinance)
        ])
          .pipe(
            map(([lookupLanguages, selectedOrdinance]) => {
              const ordinanceLanguageFormArray = new FormArray(
                lookupLanguages
                  .map(x => new FormGroup({
                    ordinanceId: new FormControl(),
                    languageCode: new FormControl(x.id),
                    ordinanceAbbreviation: new FormControl({ value: '' }, [Validators.maxLength(20), Validators.required]),
                    ...
                  })
                ));
              ordinanceLanguageFormArray.controls.forEach(item => {
                const matchingLanguage = selectedOrdinance.ordinanceLanguages?.find(
                  x => x.ordinanceId === selectedOrdinance.ordinanceId
                    && x.languageCode === item.get('languageCode').value);
                item.patchValue({
                  ordinanceId: selectedOrdinance.ordinanceId,
                  ordinanceAbbreviation: matchingLanguage?.ordinanceAbbreviation,
                  ...
                });
              });
              return ordinanceLanguageFormArray;
            }),
            catchError(error => of(new FormArray([])))
          );
      }
```

`OrdinanceLanguages` causes troubles: it depends on already available field (`selectedOrdinance` object) and also depends on Observable data which is loaded asynchronously (`languageCodesLookupData$`). I can't manage to display `ordinanceLanguages` after loading is done. The problem here is that [formGroupName] directive requires `ordinanceLanguages` form field to be filled. And I don't have idea how to transmit data from `ordinanceLanguages$` to `ordinanceLanguages` field before accessing `ordinanceLanguage.controls`. I've tried to use `ordinanceLanguages$` subscription, direct assignment using something like `ngIf="setOrdinanceLanguagesToForm(ol)` etc. But nothing works properly - I either do not get data at all or get endless output or get correct data ONLY AFTER `languageCodesLookupData$` is fully loaded..

```html
      <ng-container *ngIf="(languageCodesLookupData$ | async) && (ordinanceLanguages$ | async) as ol">
         <ng-container formArrayName="ordinanceLanguages" *ngFor="let item of ordinanceLanguages.controls; let i = index;">
           <div [formGroupName]="i">
             <div class="form-group row">...</div>
             </div>
           </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
```

Please have a look the the test example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nnosbf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

What I need to achieve is to get `ordinanceLanguages` FormArray data loaded once they are ready...

Comment: Do you have a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) ?

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code that prevent me from addressing the actual issue in the question title. First of all this code is a mess, pipes with side effects, deeply nested code, and the unnecessary `of(...)` and `combineLatest`... My advice to you is, take it step by step, dismantle this huge block of code into several small functions that do one thing each, and also avoid side effects in observable pipes.

Comment: @robert no, I've tried to start to make test example now, but now overwhelmed with 'side issues' which came up, for instance I can't add Observable there to my component for some reason, etc.

Comment: @aviad-p OK... could you please be more specific regarding 'side effects'? Do you mean using 'map' and something else? What is the alternative? The matter is this is a big project and we've been using things like that in our components from the very beginning... Unfortunately, there are no professional Angular developers here, so we try to learn 'on run'... I am always open to streamline my code, but there's just too much info around, I'd like to go step by step as you say :)

Comment: A side effect is any command that changes the state of the application. E.g. your `item.patchValue` however, now that I look at it it doesn't change app state, but at first glance it seemed like it does, which goes back to the first point, code too big, does too much, hard to understand.

Comment: @aviad-p I understand. I tried to make it as small as possible. But now I realize I must make a test sample (on StackBlitz? Ok, does not matter)... I'm trying to, but never did it and I do not know how to load test data there, etc... I will update this ticket once I will manage to do that.

Comment: You can hardcode test data with rxjs `of([{<your_test_data>},{<your_test_data>},{<your_test_data>}])`

Comment: To create a sample you don't need to setup everything you have in your real project, just what matters, and the request part can be just something like `of(…)`.

Comment: @aviad-p I've updated my question with the test example

Comment: @Alexander what is supposed to happen in that stackblitz?

Comment: @antoniossss I need to display ordinanceLanguages FormArray data on details page (clicking "Open details" button) once this data is ready (loaded). I don't mind if this data is shown record by record (language by language) or at once - when all 4 languages data is ready

Comment: So you just want to delay form creation after  this.getLanguageLookupDataApiCall() is done?

Comment: @antoniossss Initially I did not have `ordinanceLanguages` at all, i.e. Ordinance Details were loaded via one API call. Later on, it was requested to display the languages related to an `Ordinance` (i.e. `OrdinanceLanguages`) at the same detail page. One details: I need to show ALL 4 languages (i.e. system languages from language lookup) contols. And, if there is Language data for some of these 4 languages present in the selected Ordinance - it must be displayed, otherwise - just empty controls to create them on Save (for this reason I use `patchValue`).

Comment: You have this in your template `(ordinanceLanguages$ | async) as ol` but then you never refer to `ol`

Comment: @aviad-p I've tried to use it in different ways, but did not succeed to achieve what I need. So I suppose I need to figure out how to read data from `ol` to `ordinanceLanguages` FormArray, but to avoid all kind of issues (for instance, if I use something like `let item of assignFormOrdinanceAndGetThem(ol).controls` - I get endless loop of controls on my page. If I use `ol.controls` - I am getting trouble with `formGroupName` directive...

Comment: You need to first get all your data, then create your form group - your operations are all mixed with one another

Comment: Is this what you wanted? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gapevo?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Long story short, you just have to create/recreate whole form when you fetch your data

Comment: @antoniossss yes. Thank you. If you put that in the answer, I could accept it. aviad-p, thank you too. So I understand now that I cannot split details data loading and lookup loading as we do in all other pages since here lookup is vital for constructing the form... It's a bit disappointing. But if it's the only way - I'll keep it in mind for future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply delay the form creation after you fetch your data from the API, or recreate form once data is retrieved.

I have simplified littlebit your code so there is no more such mess with `Observables`. Also I have removed form patching step - just create form with proper values right away. Now, everything that is vital to the case is enclosed in `buildOrdinanceForm()`.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gapevo?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, of, debounceTime, combineLatest, map, catchError, delay } from 'rxjs';

export interface Ordinance {
  ordinanceId: number;
  ordinanceLanguages: OrdinanceLanguage[];
}

export interface OrdinanceLanguage {
  ordinanceId: number;
  languageCode: string;
  ordinanceAbbreviation: string;
}

export interface Lookup<T> {
  id: T;
  displayName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ordinanceForm: FormGroup;
  selectedOrdinance: Ordinance;
  open: boolean;
  isLoading=true;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  get ordinanceLanguages(): FormArray {
    return this.ordinanceForm.get('ordinanceLanguages') as FormArray;
  }

  getLanguageLookupDataApiCall(): Observable<Lookup<string>[]> {
    const langs = [] as Lookup<string>[];
    langs.push({ id: 'E', displayName: 'English' });
    langs.push({ id: 'I', displayName: 'Italian' });
    langs.push({ id: 'F', displayName: 'French' });
    langs.push({ id: 'G', displayName: 'German' });
    return of(langs).pipe(delay(1000));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  openDetails() {
    this.open = true;
    this.constructOrdinance();
    this.buildOrdinanceForm();
  }

  closeDetails() {
    this.open = false;
  }

  constructOrdinance() {
    this.selectedOrdinance = {
      ordinanceId: 1,
      ordinanceLanguages: [
        { languageCode: 'E', ordinanceId: 1, ordinanceAbbreviation: 'EN-1' },
        { languageCode: 'G', ordinanceId: 1, ordinanceAbbreviation: 'DE-1' }
      ]
    } as Ordinance;
  }

  buildOrdinanceForm() {
    this.isLoading=true;
    this.getLanguageLookupDataApiCall().subscribe(lookupLanguages=>{
      const ordinanceLanguageFormArray = new FormArray(
        lookupLanguages
          .map(lang => {
            const matchingLang=this.selectedOrdinance.ordinanceLanguages?.find(
              x => x.ordinanceId === this.selectedOrdinance.ordinanceId
                && x.languageCode === lang.id);
                console.log(matchingLang);
            return new FormGroup({
            ordinanceId: new FormControl(this.selectedOrdinance.ordinanceId),
            languageCode: new FormControl(lang.id),
            ordinanceAbbreviation: new FormControl(matchingLang?.ordinanceAbbreviation ?? '' ,[Validators.maxLength(20), Validators.required])});
          })
        );   
      this.ordinanceForm = this.fb.group({
        ordinanceId: [
          typeof this.selectedOrdinance.ordinanceId === 'number'
            ? this.selectedOrdinance.ordinanceId
            : null
        ],
        ordinanceLanguages: ordinanceLanguageFormArray
      });
      console.log(this.ordinanceForm.value);
    },err=>console.error(err),()=>{this.isLoading=false}
    )

  }
}
```